# media query to detect Firefox's default theme

Tags: css, firefox, themes

Is there any media query to detect if user is using Firefox's default theme

I have tried

```
@media (-moz-windows-default-theme: 1) {...}
```

but it is also triggered when I was on a custom theme (e.g. FD deep dark)
The aim is to change some colors on the UI, but they don't look good on dark themes

Answer (score 0):

You're using it incorrectly, here's the right way to use it :

```
@media (-moz-windows-default-theme) {...}
```