# How to detect Firefox Theme

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

For a WebExtension, we use `browser.browserAction.setIcon` to set the icon. As you can see in this sample, to fit in, the icon should have a dark or light background.

How can my Javascript code know which theme is in effect? Or better, can I determine what the background color for the toolbar is so I can make an appropriate icon?

[image]

Comment: This may be relevant, but is not for javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303599/media-query-to-detect-firefoxs-default-theme

Comment: Is there any CSS color name defined in Firefox that might have the current color? Something like `-moz-MenuBarText` (which doesn't seem to reflect the theme colors)?

Comment: Not an answer to the question you asked, but, according to this Firefox bug, the goal is to have you provide a monochrome SVG icon that the browser recolors. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1207597

Comment: Thanks, @ssokolow!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the theme javascript api [listed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/theme) in webextensions to get theme details. Please make sure you add "theme" permission in your `manifest.json` file.